# DNS Resolution in google Chrome

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, networking, proxy, dns

I am behind my college proxy. I am working on an open source project in which I need to modify DNS resolution so *.dev points to localhost.
I have tried by writing following line code in my .bashrc

```
alias devchrome='google-chrome --host-resolver-rules="MAP *dev localhost:8008" --user-data-dir=$HOME/devchrome --ignore-certificate-errors http://abc.net.dev/'
```

Now, When I go to my project folder and start grunt devserver. It says

```
Point your browser proxy autoconfig to one of these (or download
a local copy of one of these proxy.pacs).  Then the dev server
can be used at http://abc.net.dev/
http://127.0.0.1:8008/proxy.pac
http://10.0.0.2:8008/proxy.pac
```

Here is my http://127.0.0.1:8008/proxy.pac

```
function FindProxyForURL(url, host) {
 if (shExpMatch(host, "*.dev") || host == "drive.pencilcode.net") {
  return "PROXY 127.0.0.1:8008";
 }
 return "DIRECT";
}
```

I tried to run my chromium browser by pointing it to above file :

```
chromium-browser --proxy-pac-url="http://127.0.0.1:8008/proxy.pac"
```

At the end my I entered abc.net.dev in the browser then It takes me to my college proxy default page[proxy.iiit.ac.in] instead of taking me to index of abc.net.dev.

Logs of terminal where chromium browser is running:

```
[5804:5804:0314/162341:ERROR:desktop_window_tree_host_x11.cc(1478)] Not implemented reached in void views::DesktopWindowTreeHostX11::MapWindow(ui::WindowShowState)
ATTENTION: default value of option force_s3tc_enable overridden by environment.
```

Logs where my devserver is running
Express server listening on 8008

Running "node-inspector:dev" (node-inspector) task

```
Node Inspector v0.7.4
Visit http://127.0.0.1:8080/debug?port=5858 to start debugging.
ImmediateReturnError: Host 127.0.0.1 not part of domain abc.net.dev ip:127.0.0.1 ua:Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.76 Safari/537.36 url:/favicon.ico
```

I have configured my system proxy settings as my college's proxy domain name and port. I tried it by changing to the localhost as domain name and 8008[ which is mentioned in grunt devserver] as port. After this configuration, Instead of pointing to my college's default proxy page, It tries to go to the abc.net.dev but as abc.net.dev has some rest api calls which says PROXY_CONNECTION_REFUSED. I think It is because I am not able to connect to internet as I have changed my proxy to localhost. I think there must be some other way arround.

Can someone please tell me where I am going wrong and how to correct it.